# How to use AsyncResource when implementing a worker pool?

Tags: node.js

[`worker_threads`](https://nodejs.org/api/worker_threads.html) documentation is suggesting to:

> When implementing a worker pool, use the `AsyncResource` API to inform diagnostic tools (e.g. in order to provide asynchronous stack traces) about the correlation between tasks and their outcomes.

However, there is no example.

What is an example usage for `AsyncResource` to capture asynchronous stack traces of a task scheduled using `worker_threads`?